# Netbeans MVC Swing JTable ResultSet data insert

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller, netbeans, jtable

I'm new to Java, Swing and programming, but I need to make an application. I'm using NetBeans for development and here's my question:

If I drag and drop the JTable to my frame and select custom code for the table, I get this code:

**appView.java**

```
tblViewData = new javax.swing.JTable();

tblViewData.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
    new Object [][] {

    },
    new String [] {
        "ID", "Reference No", "Name", "Description"
    }
));



jScrollPane1.setViewportView(tblViewData);
```

What I want to do is populate **new Objects[][]** with data that I fetch from the **appController** using ResultSet and the values I set in the **appModel** for variables ID, Ref, Name and Desc.

Here's a sample code of an insert I attempted to see if I could display a row of data:

```
    new Object [][] {
        { new Integer(model.getID()), model.getRef(), model.getName(), model.getDesc() }
    },
```

This code returns a 0 in the first column of the row.

Am I approaching this problem wrong?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Well I have no idea what the "appController" or "appModel" are. Maybe these are IDE dependent classes? Instead of using the IDE to generate your SQL code I suggest you write your own code and populate the table yourself.

There are plenty of examples on the forum showing how to load a `JTable` with data from a `ResultSet`. Just search for examples using those two class names as your keywords.

Or you can check out [Table From Database](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/03/12/table-from-database/) which shows how you can use the `DefaultTableModel` to load rows of data from the `ResultSet`.